# Unsupported index types through migrations. Schema:update wants to remove some

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a symfony 3.4.2 + doctrine 2.6 project using postgresql 9.6. I am trying to add some unsupported index types. I found [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6744) which points out that migrations should be used for this purpose.

My problem is that the migrations work for 2 out of 3 indices. But `doctrine:schema:update` wants 3rd index to be dropped.

I have a `Product` entity with no index definition. I have created 2 indices using migrations. `name` is `character varying(255)` type.

```
"idx_product_name_gin_trgm_ops" gin (lower(name::text) gin_trgm_ops)
"idx_product_name_varchar_pattern_ops" btree (lower(name::text) varchar_pattern_ops)
```

This is all fine. But I have `Store` entity, again with no index definition. I have created gist index using migrations. The `coords` is a `geography(Point,4326)` type.

```
"idx_store_coords_gist" gist (coords)
```

Now the problem is that when I execute `doctrine:schema:update` I receive:

```
 The following SQL statements will be executed:

     DROP INDEX idx_store_coords_gist;
```

Why does it not care at all about my other indices and wants to drop this one only?